# Find key in dictionary with most unique values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, set

I have a dictionary of lists:

```
dict_one = {'a': ['Hanks', 'Bob', 'Bill'], 'b': ['nation', 'nile', 'Jonas']}
```

***the dictionary above was only an example it could be extremely long***

I need to find to the key with the most unique set of names or words.

I need both the key and the actual length of the key

So far, I have been able to find the actual length of the unique list pretty easily with the code below:

```
print(max(len(set(x)) for x in dict_one.values()))
```

But now I am struggling with finding the key itself. I need to print the length and the key itself as said prior. For example, an output might look like this:

```
key: a
length: 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're pretty close. did you know that max can take a `key` the same way that `sort` can? check this out:

```
max(dict_one.items(), key=lambda x: len(set(x[1])))
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to get only the key with this though? I just added this in and one method that worked was this: print(max(movies.items(), key=lambda x: len(set(x[1])))[0]). Is this the correct way?

Comment: @Linus yep, you got it